# How to print the numbers in 3 rows as per order?

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, stringbuilder

```
<body>
    <%
        int apps = 11;
        out.println("<div>");
        out.println("<table>");
        StringBuilder Row1 = new StringBuilder();
        Row1.append("<tr>");
        StringBuilder Row2 = new StringBuilder();
        Row2.append("<tr>");
        StringBuilder Row3 = new StringBuilder();
        Row3.append("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < apps; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                Row1.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                Row2.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
        }
        Row1.append("</tr>");
        Row2.append("</tr>");
        out.println(Row1.toString());
        out.println(Row2.toString());
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
    %>
</body>
```

this is my jsp page,

**Currently** i'm getting the output as

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now **I need** the output as

In **row 1**:

```
0 3 6 9 12 15
```

In **row 2**:

```
1 4 7 10 13
```

In **row 3**:

```
2 5 8 11 14
```

If I have 100 numbers, output needs as above.

Comment: add a java tag,more chances of gettting ur answer

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like when you access the page?

Comment: also wat happens in the 4th row..do u need 3 6 9 12 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a PHP developer, I did it in php way. But logic is same..

```
<?php

$apps = 100;
for ($i = 0; $i < $apps; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $row1 .= "<td>" .$i ."</td>";
    }
    if ($i % 3 == 1) {
        $row2 .= "<td>" .$i ."</td>";
    }
    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
        $row3 .= "<td>" .$i ."</td>";
    }
}
?>
<table>
<tr><?php echo $row1; ?></tr>
<tr><?php echo $row2;?></tr>
<tr><?php echo $row3; ?></tr>
</table>
```

Change appropriate places and check..

Comment: Missing 3rd row elemets(2,5,8,..ect)please check your output once.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < apps; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        Row1.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
    } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
        Row2.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
    } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
        Row3.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
    }
}
```

**ADDITION**:

you haven't printed out the third row..
try to add this:

```
Row3.append("</tr>");
out.println(Row3.toString());
```

Comment: Missing 3rd row elemets(2,5,8,..ect)please check your output once.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to stop using java code in your jsp pages as that can become quite brittle. An alternative would be to use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/). Your page would then be translated to something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <c:set var="apps" value="10"/>
    <tr>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${apps}" step="3">
       <td><c:out value="${i}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${apps}" step="3">
       <td><c:out value="${i}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="2" end="${apps}" step="3">
       <td><c:out value="${i}"/></td>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

This way it is easier to keep a clean separation between your buisness-logic and your view-logic (which generates the page).